# Android: Making drawables clickable

Tags: android, google-maps

Currently, I have an Android application that places icons on Google Maps. I was wondering if there was a way to make my drawables clickable so I can have a pop up menu giving the user some sort of menu options. I am implementing the drawables like this:

```
Drawable drawable1 = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("pics/pin1.png"), null);    
CustomItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay1 = new CustomItemizedOverlay(drawable1, this);

GeoPoint point1 = new GeoPoint(latitudep1, longitudep1);
OverlayItem overlayitem1 = new OverlayItem(point1, "Icon", "#1");

itemizedOverlay1.addOverlay(overlayitem1);
mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay1);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are u using mapviewballoon library..

Comment: see this https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

Comment: No I'm not. Could I just set onClickListeners on them and make an onOptionsItemSelected?

Comment: no its not possible. use onTap() function in customizedOVerlay class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```
public class AddItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

private Context context;
Intent intent;
MapView mapview;

public AddItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
}

public AddItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    this(defaultMarker);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return mapOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return mapOverlays.size();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    OverlayItem item = mapOverlays.get(index);

    /*intent = new Intent(context, Locationdisplay.class);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);// changed

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("namevalue", item.getTitle());
    intent.putExtras(bundle);

    context.startActivity(intent);*/
        Toast.makeText(context, "tapped", 1).show();

    return true;
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mapOverlays.add(overlay);
    this.populate();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if possible, but can you display ImageViews instead of Drawables on your map? With ImageViews it would be easy to use the click events on them.